# what does `tcpdump -xx` do in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, tcpdump

I was playing with `tcpdump`, and I noticed that, on OS X, the `-xx` option does something that is different to what the man page describes.

Here is what the `man` page says:

```
   -x     When parsing and printing, in addition to printing the headers of each packet, print the data of each packet (minus its link level header) in hex.
          The  smaller  of  the entire packet or snaplen bytes will be printed.  Note that this is the entire link-layer packet, so for link layers that pad
          (e.g. Ethernet), the padding bytes will also be printed when the higher layer packet is shorter than the required padding.

   -xx    When parsing and printing, in addition to printing the headers of each packet, print the data of each packet, including its link level header,  in
          hex.
```

So if I understand correctly, `-xx` would show me the ethernet header while `-x` won't. This is true on Linux. However, on OS X, `-x` shows me the ethernet header while `-xx` put some extra junk in front of it. As you can see, the ethernet header `0886 3b60 1d3c 28cf e919 a36d 0800` appears in both `-x` and `-xx`, and in `-xx` it appears in the line marked by `0x0060` and I've no idea what the data come before it means.

Here is one sample output of `tcpdump -xx` on OS X:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -Sxx -e -n port 33407
tcpdump: data link type PKTAP
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on pktap, link-type PKTAP (Packet Tap), capture size 65535 bytes
11:10:11.177881 28:cf:e9:19:a3:6d > 08:86:3b:60:1d:3c, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 78: 192.168.2.8.49923 > 23.239.3.247.33407: Flags [S], seq 1859065803, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 4,nop,nop,TS val 461417464 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
    0x0000:  6c00 0000 0100 0000 0100 0000 656e 3000
    0x0010:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
    0x0020:  0000 0000 0200 0000 0200 0000 0e00 0000
    0x0030:  0000 0000 4f10 0100 7373 6800 0000 0000
    0x0040:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
    0x0050:  0600 0000 ffff ffff 0000 0000 0000 0000
    0x0060:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0886 3b60
    0x0070:  1d3c 28cf e919 a36d 0800 4500 0040 66af
    0x0080:  4000 4006 f572 c0a8 0208 17ef 03f7 c303
    0x0090:  827f 6ecf 17cb 0000 0000 b002 ffff c4d1
    0x00a0:  0000 0204 05b4 0103 0304 0101 080a 1b80
    0x00b0:  abf8 0000 0000 0402 0000
```

And here is one sample output of `tcpdump -x`:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -Sxvv -e -n port 33407
tcpdump: data link type PKTAP
tcpdump: listening on pktap, link-type PKTAP (Packet Tap), capture size 65535 bytes
11:10:48.727138 28:cf:e9:19:a3:6d > 08:86:3b:60:1d:3c, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 102: (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 25163, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 88)
    192.168.2.8.49923 > 23.239.3.247.33407: Flags [P.], cksum 0x1126 (correct), seq 1859067461:1859067497, ack 2295673726, win 8192, options [nop,nop,TS val 461454802 ecr 120336925], length 36
    0x0000:  0886 3b60 1d3c 28cf e919 a36d 0800 4510
    0x0010:  0058 624b 4000 4006 f9ae c0a8 0208 17ef
    0x0020:  03f7 c303 827f 6ecf 1e45 88d5 337e 8018
    0x0030:  2000 1126 0000 0101 080a 1b81 3dd2 072c
    0x0040:  321d cdac 025c 44d7 8043 f45e da96 1c0d
    0x0050:  fbf3 de02 c17e 03ef 1014 d6da 506f c0c3
    0x0060:  a405 8cbd fcdc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not an Ethernet header at the beginning of those packets.  The link-layer header type is DLT_PKTAP, and [this is what its headers look like](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes/LINKTYPE_PKTAP.html).

You'll get a similar surprise if you capture in monitor mode on OS X - *or Linux!* - as the packets will probably begin with [radiotap headers](http://www.radiotap.org).

The documentation, and tcpdump itself, were written in a simpler era, before we had link layers where there's a reason to have a lot of metadata (such as 802.11 and the metadata for layers below the MAC layer) and mechanisms for providing other sorts of metadata (such as PKTAP provides).

Tcpdump should perhaps distinguish between metadata headers and link-layer headers, default to not showing the metadata layers with `-xx` and only dump them with `-xxx`, or something such as that.  You might want to file a bug on that on [the tcpdump issue tracker](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/issues).  (There should probably be some discussion, as that would be an incompatible change to the output of tcpdump.)

As for *not* getting DLT_PKTAP, try capturing on a particular interface, using the `-i` flag; tcpdump in Yosemite defaults to capturing on *all* network interfaces simultaneously.  On Linux, that can be done by capturing on the "any" interface - which *also* doesn't give you Ethernet headers, it gives you [Linux cooked capture headers](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes/LINKTYPE_LINUX_SLL.html) - but it doesn't *default* to the "any" interface; on Yosemite, it defaults to capturing on all interfaces simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. I've no idea about the link layer :D. I choose to not file a bug this time, will see if that's worth doing as I learn more about it ;-).